# Different sort direction for each sortable attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

is it possible to have different Default Sort Direction for different sortable attributes?

is sort direction a value that can be changed using updateAttribute or is the sort direction global?

thank you

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, mind giving a full example of what you'd want achieved?

Comment: For example I would like when the user selects sort by price the direction to be asc, but when he selects sort by date the direction to be desc.
So I would like to know if an attribute has something like a 'default sorting direction', but if I understand Marius' answer below there is not such a thing. 
Hope this clears out what I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting direction is not attribute dependent.
attribute and direction are 2 different independent criteria.
The direction can be selected by the user. and when changing the sorting attribute it defaults to ASC.

Comment: so I guess I could use some js to change the direction if the user selects another sorting method.
Thank you!